# PaaS provider for Grails application for production use

Tags: grails, cloud

I have an application developed by **Grails 2.5.1** , i need PaaS provider to deploy it for production use , but must got these options :

1. SMTP server as my application needs to send emails
2. preferred to have access to file system but not necessary
3. MYSql DB
4. Able to deploy PHP applications in it.
5. Easy to deploy application's packages on
6. Good customer support

some adviced  with Jelastic , but unfortunately they don't have SMTP server , and Heroku  the deploying in it is a little bit hard.

any recommendations?

Comment: I suggest Google Cloud, much better than suggested AWS. You could use Google Appengine with ManagedVM, that better works with Grails. Or Kubernetes/Cloud Instances, for full flexibility

Comment: An alternative is to get a VPS instead of a PaaS. You'd be able to install and configure everything you need. To deploy WARs use a Mercurial repository with a changegroup hook. I suppose that if the VPS can run Docker or LXC, you can use that as the deployment unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheriff

It is very easy to add SMTP to Jelastic.
All you need to set up your SMPT Server [is here](https://docs.jelastic.com/adding-mail-server-vps).

Also, how to use external SMTP Server in your environment - [is here](https://docs.jelastic.com/email-via-external-smtp).

With reference to the rest of your list Jelastic provides:

- Access to file system ([FTP/FTPS](https://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support), [SFTP/FISH](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-protocols), [WebDAV](https://docs.jelastic.com/remote-access-via-webdav), [Dashboard](https://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-dashboard-guide))
- [MYSql DB](https://docs.jelastic.com/connection-to-mysql-php)
- [Able to deploy PHP applications in it](https://docs.jelastic.com/php-versions)
- Easy to deploy application's packages on ([Direct](https://docs.jelastic.com/whole-project-deploying), [GIT/SVN](https://docs.jelastic.com/docs/php-git-svn), [Bitbucket](https://docs.jelastic.com/docs/deploying-php-bitbucket-project))
- Good customer support (You can choose hoster by your significant criteria [here](https://jelastic.cloud/)).

Have a nice day,
Jelastic Support

Comment: thanks for this useful information , the person i contacted didn't share this helpful information .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Heroku or Elastic Beanstalk. Amazon RDS for MySQL as a Service, or Aurora which is MySQL compatible.

Not sure what you mean by "able to deploy PHP". You won't be able to run a PHP app and a Grails/Java app on the same PaaS server, but you could spin up a separate PHP app on the same PaaS.

You could use Amazon SES to send emails, or a SendGrid account. Email server really shouldn't be a deciding factor.

Comment: I agree with this recommendation. AWS Elastic Beanstalk with an independent RDS instance (not one created by Elastic Beanstalk) is a very good option. We do all of our production instances with it now and they all send messages using the Grails Mail plugin using standard SMTP.